# I am using axis to generate client classes. I need to use log4j in my application

Tags: java, log4j, apache-axis

However when i use Logger.debug , the axis   generated classes also writes in my log files. I want only the log information of the project alone. Can any one help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should configure distinct logger for classes of your application.

In properties configuration it should be like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR,stdout
log4j.logger.com.yourapp.rootpackage=INFO,logfile
```

I mean here that **stdout** is a console appender, and **logfile** is a file appender. Package **com.yourapp.rootpackage** is the root package of classes of your application.

As you can see only logger that's associated with classes of your application will be writing to log file appender. Root logger (logger that's associated with all classes) is writing to console.

I reccomend you to learn more about configuration and all the possibilities of log4j.

Answer (score 0):

adding the below code to your log4j.xml will prevent the axis generated classes to write the logs onto your debug file.

`<logger name="org.apache.axis">
        <level value="info"/>
    </logger>`

If you are using properties file to configure use

```
log4j.category.org.apache.axis=INFO
```